# How to mock ObjectResult.FirstOrDefault() using Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, moq

I'm doing an ASP.Net MVC2 project and developing some unit test cases on it. In one of my controllers,

```
String AllowedActions = "";
AllowedActions = entities.sp_IsAuthorized(GetLoggedUserId(), 1, item.SubCategoryId, "CreateMeeting_HTML").FirstOrDefault();
```

I was unable to mock this sp_IsAuthorized() method ,

```
    public ObjectResult<global::System.String> sp_IsAuthorized(.....){

}
```

I tried to mock it in this way,

```
var entity = new Mock<TestMVCProductEntities>();
entity.Setup(x => x.sp_IsAuthorized(...)).Return(???);
```

but I have no clue how to return

ObjectResult

this type of object. Help me.

Comment: Mocq can only mock `virtual` methods so if `sp_IsAuthorized` is not virtual it won't work at all.

Comment: @nemesv
Ya.It is. But my problem is what should i return in this statement,

   entity.Setup(x => x.sp_IsAuthorized(...)).Return(???);

I have put the question marks.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized that code is probably automatically generated so you won't change the return type. I suggest you to read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff714955.aspx) about testability and Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new instance of ObjectResult and you can't mock it because it is marked as sealed. I would recommend you to wrap your usage of the data context into a unit of work or similar pattern, making it testable in a unit test.

Comment: I usually wrap my context (LINQ to SQL and EntityFramework) and session (NHibernate) in repositories. This makes it possible to mock the repositories in the classes dependant of data. The Repository pattern with ObjectContext is described in detail in this blog post: http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/

Comment: As of the time of this comment, it's not sealed.